# How to apply svg symbols as point markers in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I must be overlooking something obvious!

I've just downloaded and launched QGIS 2.0. I'm trying to edit a layer's symbol markers to use a more descriptive icon. Opening layer properties and then clicking the style tab, I only see a very limited collection of symbols. Clicking style manager too, I can't see any way to increase the symbols available.

Looking inside the application package, there is a folder `resources` which contains an `svg` folder full of the icons I'm looking for. How do I apply these as markers to a point layer?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to select the symbol item itself and change it to SVG icon

[image]

You can even stack simple symbols and SVG symbols

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nathan, would have spent hours trying to figure this out. Knew I was missing something obvious! I was looking at "Marker" in the tree, rather than the "simple marker" layer below, hence overlooking the layer type selector.

Comment: Yeah the Marker level refers to the whole symbol and it's layers as a collection. You can change for example the size and it will scale all the children symbols.